# How to build and interpret Q-Q plots when data can be grouped by a factor

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, qq-plot

I have a dataset $D=\{(\mathbf{x}_i,y_i)\}_{i=1}^N$, with $N\sim150$. The data come from 7 different test campaigns, which are not mere repetitions of the same tests, but actually different tests with different values of the $\mathbf{x}_i$ and thus of the $y_i$.

Using Nonlinear Least Squares I calibrated a physical model for the experimental results, and I'm having a look at the residuals, to understand if one of the assumptions behind the NLS framework (Gaussian errors) is valid or not. Of course I don't have access to errors, thus, as usual, I will look at the residuals. Here they are:
[image]

Clearly, while all tests have a few points which "stray away" from normality, it looks like test campaign E has the most points away the central line(mostly below it), while campaign D and A have a few points below the central line (A also has a very extreme residual above the central line).

I tried to get more information by building a QQ plot for each test campaign, but here I have many doubts (**EDIT**: as suggested by whuber, I updated the facet plots with `scales="free_y"`):[image]

1. If my current visualization is ok for the purpose of judging the validity of the assumptions behind NLS, then which are the tests where I should be most worried about? A & E? In this case, should I fit 3 separate nonlinear models - one to data from test A, one to data from test E and the other to data from all remaining tests? My idea is that maybe tests such as A & E need radically different values of the calibration parameters $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ wrt the other tests, because something physical was really different. As a matter of fact, at least for test E there was a physical variable whose values were quite  different from those used in other tests. Thus it makes sense that $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ should be different too.
2. Can you get any other useful intuitions from these data? If you need to see more plots (for example, a residuals vs expected plot) just let me know.

Comment: There are subtle indications of bimodality in some of these plots (except for $E$) that aren't apparent because you're drawing them with common vertical axes.  To read these well, each plot's points should trend roughly along a 45 degree line.  Use `+ facet_wrap(scales="free_y")` instead and consider using weighted nonlinear least squares, with separate weights for each campaign.  Non-gaussianity of the errors should be the least of your concerns.

Comment: @whuber thanks! Tomorrow I will regenerate the plots with `scales="free_y"` and update the post. About WNLS, any suggestions on how to choose the weights? The test team provided "estimates" of the measurement errors. I might use their inverses as weights, but I don't trust those estimates much. Maybe I could verify if they at least predict larger errors for the points where I got larger residuals. What do you think?

Comment: Use the reciprocals of the variances of the residuals for each campaign.

Comment: @whuber ok. So, that would be $w_i=\frac {1}{1-h_{ii}}$ where the  $h_{ii}$ are the diagonal terms of the Fisher information matrix evaluated at the estimated parameters vector $\boldsymbol {\theta}^*$. Correct?

Comment: No, that's far too precise.  All you need are rough but reliable estimates of the variances for each campaign.  It is important *not* to rely on the hat matrix, because its values might vary within a campaign, whereas you want the weights to depend *only* on the campaigns.  (For the simplest model, where the campaign is the sole regressor, this won't make any difference; but if you're including other regressor variables, it can make a big difference.)

Comment: @whuber I modified the facet plot as you suggested. Can you let me know if a) bimodality is confirmed, b) how it is detected from the QQ plot and c) what should I do in case of bimodality? I'm trying to setup  WNLS, but that needs a little more time, and I'm on a pretty tight schedule now - I'll let you know as soon as I update the post.

Comment: (+1) The new graphics are much more effective!  Bimodality (or, more generally, evidence of a mixture) manifests itself as either (1) an S-shape in the curve, with the steepest inflection in the middle tapering off to the ends; or (2) a kink joining two nearly-linear sections.  The latter is clear in $E$ and somewhat evident in $D$.  $A$ has obvious multi-modal characteristics that are hard to diagnose due to so few data.  The others, including $B$, do not appear to deviate significantly from normality. The best solution is to find a regressor that distinguishes the two components.